# Not getting data from firestore using firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I created a firebase function to test how to get data from a firebase function. However, I am not able to get any data.

Note: I have another function that is listing all user from Authentication without any problem.

Here is my code:

```
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccountKey.json');

// Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });

const db = admin.firestore();

export const listUserProfiles = onRequest(async (request, response) => {    
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    try {
        const ref = db.collection("UserProfiles").doc("cnZbRQtnCnQ52kTbcxI6Zq7d3VA3");
        const docSnap = await ref.get();
        if (docSnap.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
            response.status(200).json(docSnap.data());
        } else {
            console.log("No such UserProfiles!");
            response.status(200).json({});
        }
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log('Error Getting profile:', error);
        response.status(500);
        response.statusMessage = `Error Getting profile: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`;
        response.send(error);
    }
        
})
```

When I hit the endpoint the log is showing `No such UserProfiles!`

I have a firestore rules that allow read for this collection.
I already checked the document `cnZbRQtnCnQ52kTbcxI6Zq7d3VA3` and it is exists on the collection

Why I am not getting data?

I am expecting return the content of the document

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so the problem is likely somewhere that we can't see. I recommend checking all the constants (`"UserProfiles" and `"cnZbRQtnCnQ52kTbcxI6Zq7d3VA3"`) in your code once more. If those really look fine, it may be good to try and read a document with a simpler name (like `"test")` or [read multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) (so you don't need to hardcode a name).

Comment: I found the problem. Shame on me. I was running the emulator. On the emulator, there was no data. After pushing it into the cloud the data shows up. Tks for your help @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, shame on me. I was running the emulator and I found out there was no data on it.

```
firebase emulators:start
```

After pushing it into the cloud the data shows up.

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the keyword `exists` can you try to check `docSnap.data()` instead

```
export const listUserProfiles = onRequest(async (request, response) => {    
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    try {
        const ref = db.collection("UserProfiles").doc("cnZbRQtnCnQ52kTbcxI6Zq7d3VA3");
        const docSnap = await ref.get();
        const data = docSnap.data();

        if (data === undefined) {
            console.log("No such UserProfiles!");
            response.status(200).json({});
        } else {
            console.log("Document data:", data);
            response.status(200).json(data);
        }
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log('Error Getting profile:', error);
        response.status(500);
        response.statusMessage = `Error Getting profile: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`;
        response.send(error);
    }
        
})
```

also add `databaseURL` in your `admin.initializeApp`

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: DB_URL
});
```

Comment: I tried, however, I got `undefined`

Comment: try to specify your database url when initializeApp

Comment: I found the problem. Shame on me. I was running the emulator. On the emulator, there was no data. After pushing it into the cloud the data shows up. I appreciate your effort to solve it.